# Is apache tomcat web server or app server

Tags: tomcat

Is apache tomcat web server or application server? 
can apache tomcat be used as web server as well as application server in same environment?

Answer (score 0):

It's a servlet container that can also serve files via http, so yes, it's a webserver.

Traditionally in the Java ecosystem, "full" appservers consist of a servlet container, ejb container and a slew of supporting technologies and APIs like message oriented middleware (JMS), timer management, and so on. Standard Tomcat is just the servlet container, so it doesn't match the traditional definition of an appserver.

[TomEE](http://tomee.apache.org/apache-tomee.html) is a prepackaged distribution of Tomcat with a number of these traditional EE components added, that in many cases can replace a full appserver like Wildfly or Glassfish/Payara.

By the way, Tomcat can also run php via [Quercus](http://quercus.caucho.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the info @fvu